# Rounding percentage in css correctly

Tags: css

If you can't/won't use calc() what is the correct way to round percentage values for, for example, widths, to get around the sub pixel problem.
The reason I cant use calc() is, according to caniuse.com it's not supported in any of Opera Mini browsers, and I don't want to leave those out.

Here are a few examples I have that need correct rounding:

```
29.1666666667%
33.3333333333%
14.2857142857%
16.6666666667%
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Assuming you have JS and want to round to N decimal places, you add `0.<0*N>5` to the number (where "<0*n>" is N zeros) to the number, convert to a string and then truncate of the digits more than N places past the decimal point.  So if you want to truncate 14.2857142857 to 3 decimal places, you add 0.0005 to it (for 14.2862142857) and then trim the last 7 digits for `14.286`.

Comment: Its for a grid, so i cant have it add up to m ore than 100% . I guess that's where the sub pixel problem occur. I appreciate your answer, but my maths is bad, could you give one example from one of the percentages in my original post please :)

Comment: Done.  (you need to use "@<personsName>" in comments so we get notices when you respond).

Comment: @RBarryYoung Thank you! And how many decimals would one need when doing this for widths of divs would you say? 3 is more than enough isnt it?

Comment: @FrankUnderwood Some comments. 1) Calc can't round either, so that wouldn't have been a big help anyway. 2) Rounding to a specific percentage won't solve the subpixel problems, and 3) Most browsers use floats for storing their values, so around 7 or 8 digits is the most they can handle in terms of precision. You won't get exactly 33 and 1/3 percents.

Comment: Thank you for explaining @MrLister . I realized the rounding and did it via php instead. All solved, thanks again guys :)